# Embed a file into a Word doc using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am attempting to do this from Access 2010 using Word 2010. I have a WordDoc object and cannot find a way to embed a file.

I tried starting from nothing using a bookmark:

```
bmFile.Range.InsertFile "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\TestFile.xlsx"
```

and that trew an error about the File being corrupted.

I tried editing an existing embeded file using `WordDoc.InlineShapes(1)` but no properties were changable or relevant.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an existing file (as per your example) you should be able to do this

```
bmFile.Range.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="Excel.Sheet.12", _
  FileName:="C:\Users\Me\Desktop\TestFile.xlsx", _
  LinkToFile:=False, _
  DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

It's actually nastier to insert an object without using a file. You can do it by setting the FileName parameter to "", but then the OLE server will be started and display its UI (which doesn't happen when you embed from a file).

As for modifying anything in the embedded object, it isn't particularly straightforward because the object's UI tends to get in the way, but the starting point is the OLEFormat member of the Shape (or InlineShape). Difficult to find because "OLEFormat" is not a particularly informative name.

Comment: My actual implementation was `bmFile.Range.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject "Excel.Sheet.12", "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\TestFile.xlsx", False, True, "C:\Windows\Installer\{90140000-0011-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}\xlicons.exe", 1, "New.xlsx"` which shows the Excel Icon and the name

Answer (score 2):

```
theWordDocObject.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject _
    FileName:="pathtofile", _
    LinkToFile:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

(works at least with Excel files)